# Removing an image border using opencv

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv, border

I have a lot of images with a thick white border around them. What's the easiest way for me to remove/isolate these borders? Anyway I can do this using OpenCV?

Comment: Post an example representative image.  Are the borders all the same width?  Are they parallel to the image boundary (so vertical and horizontal only) or at an angle?  Be specific.

Comment: As misha asked before, do the images all have the same border width? Then the problem becomes quite simple: if the width of border is say `w` then create a `cvRect` with `x` and `y` = `w`, `width=(img->width - 2*w)` and `height=(img->height - 2*w)`. Basically create a rectangle that excludes the border region. Then just use the 'setImageROI()` to set the image's ROI to the rectangle and save it.

Comment: The borders aren't the same width, but are always horizontal and vertical and not at an angle. So, it's unclear where the border ends and the image begins. I thought of binary searching for a row (in the case of a horizontal border), but instead just went with a scan that begins at a fixed number of rows/columns into the image. A bit slow, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not a very elegant solution, but here's my first attempt.

```
            if( direction == BORDER_SEARCH_DIRECTION.TOP || 
            direction == BORDER_SEARCH_DIRECTION.BOTTOM )
        {
            for (int y = startY; y >= 0 && y < _image.Height; y += deltaY)
            {
                bool foundNonWhite = false;
                for (int x = startX; x < _image.Width; x += deltaX)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(_image.ManagedArray.GetValue(y, x, 0)) < BORDER_WHITENESS_THRESHOLD)
                    {
                        foundNonWhite = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!foundNonWhite)
                {
                    borderAt = y;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Basically, this assumes that a border will start at most a fifth of the way into the image from the top/bottom, and it searches for the first row that is completely "white". I run the routine twice and if I find an entire row of white on the top and bottom of the image, I assume we have a border.

Damn thing takes 250 milliseconds.

Answer (score -1):

One approach would be to use quad-tree decomposition such that the border area is a "leaf" node. Then you can subtract it out.